# D7 Views - trim a tag and it's content?

Tags: views

In my view I have a long text field. There's h1 tag on every entity that I want to remove (and content within h1). Does anyone know a way to do this?

Basically I want this :

## Title

Content

To become this:

Content

Comment: You can check box Exclude in view settings which will hide field ... Does your view Display set to content or fields ?

Comment: This is a single field (long text). I want to remove h1 tag and it's content from it. Basically trim h1 and its content.

Comment: You can check Exclude Checkbox in view Title field settings or remove the field itself from the list...

Comment: @Qweick If I understand you correctly, then the title tag is part of the text field? It's not a separate field? In that case the exclude option can't work. Basically you are asking for a text preprocessor that allows you to remove a part of the text using a regular expression. Is that the case?

Comment: Yeah. I've worked it out though, thanks :)